# How can I get the HttpRequest object in an ApiController without using the HttpContext static class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to get the `HttpRequest` (not `HttpRequestMessage`) object without using the `HttpContext` static class in my `ApiController`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>()
```

Instead of what I can have in a regular `Controller` which is a regular property instance:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>()
```

Is there a way to have something right from the instance of the ApiController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContext;
```

or for Web API:

```
var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!